# ggplot2: applying width of line to the legend key

Tags: r, ggplot2

Considering the data.frame "dfc":

```
dfc <- structure(list(lag = c(-5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
       4L, 5L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("var1", "var2"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 
2.4, 3, 3.6, 4.2, 4.8, 5.4, 6, 6.6), size = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("lag", 
"variable", "value", "size"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like:

```
head(dfc)
  lag variable value size
1  -5     var1     1    2
2  -4     var1     2    2
3  -3     var1     3    2
4  -2     var1     4    2
5  -1     var1     5    2
6   0     var1     6    2
```

I would like to plot "value" against "lag" with different line styles (depending on "variable) and widths (depending on "size"). I achieved with this piece of code:

```
ggplot(dfc) +
geom_line(aes(x = lag, y = value, linetype = variable, size = size)) +
scale_size(range=c(1, 2), guide=FALSE) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, labels = c("Name of var1    ", "Name of var2")) +
theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

Giving this plot:
[image]

But I cannot figure out how, at the same, to change the size of the line inside the legend, accordingly, and to keep the renaming.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
z <- ggplot(dfc) + 
     geom_line(aes(x = lag, y = value, linetype = variable, size = size)) + 
     scale_size(range=c(1, 2), guide=FALSE)
z <- z + theme(legend.key.width = unit(5,"cm"))
z <- z + guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2)))
z
```

I have added the `guides()` function to my previous answer.

After increasing the width of the `legend.key.width`, size of the lines in the legend can be changed by using the `override.aes` parameter and assigning it to the `linetype` variable.
[image]

This can be other way than what @cogitovita proposed.

Comment: `var2` should be 1, not 2. And as said, I don't need to change the width of the key.

Comment: It works with `list(size = c(2,1))` in `guide_legend`.

Comment: To clarify: `legend.key.width` changes the *width* of the legend symbol (in this case a line), while `list(size = 2)` increases the *thickness* (or height) of the line in the legend.

Comment: Since ggplot 3.4.0 the line size argument changed from `size` to `linewidth`. But in there is no warning about this in the `guide_legend()` function. The correct call would be `guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = 2))`

Answer (score 4):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

z <- ggplot(dfc) + geom_line(aes(x = lag, y = value, linetype = variable, size = size)) + 
     scale_size(range=c(1, 2), guide=FALSE)

z <- z + theme(legend.key.width = unit(5,"cm"))
```

[image]

Width of the Legend is changed using `legend.key.width` parameter in the `ggplot2` library package

You can change the numeric value of the width. Loading the `grid` library is important. Else the 'unit' is not recognized by R.

Comment: No, sorry, it doesn't. I confess my request wasn't clear. I would like to change the size of the lines in the legend, not the length/width of the key itself.

Answer (score 4):

Since `dfc` is grouped by `$variable` and `$size` is constant within each group. Try extract `$size` and set it manually.

```
var_size = c('var1'=2, 'var2'=1)
ggplot(dfc) + 
geom_line(aes(x = lag, y = value, linetype = variable, size=variable)) + 
scale_size_manual(values=var_size)
```

[image]

Comment: OK. I now realize my own question doesn't fit my needs. I have to edit it.